# how can I remove T00:00:00.000Z angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How can i remove T00:00:00.000Z in angular . I use

```
  ng-model-options="{timezone:'UTC'}"
```

And ng-model display `2017-04-24T00:00:00.000Z` . I only want display `2017-04-24` Is there the way to do that ?

Comment: Convert your input date to your expected format.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to take a look at the [date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

`{{ date_expression | date : format : timezone}}`

`{{ someDatePropertyInModel | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd' : 'UTC' }}`

**Edit**

If you want the value to be stored in the model you can use `ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }"` and bind to a setter value that uses the JS version of this filter.

```
<input type="date" name="something"
             ng-model="modelObject.something"
             ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }" />
```

And in the controller

```
var _someDate;
$scope.modelObject = {
  something: function(value) {
    return arguments.length ? _someDate = $filter('date')(value, 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'UTC') : _someDate);)
  }
};
```

Comment: not quite so simple in `ng-model`...can't use inline filters

Comment: So you want to actually store this value in the model and not just for display?

Comment: I'm not the OP. Was just pointing it out since answer didn't address it. Can have different display value than model value in ng-model but can't use inline filter